# Python: how to get edge’s index when indexes of two vertices are given?

Tags: python

How do I get index of an edge when indexes of two vertices which making the edge are given? (By index I mean the number you put in the [] to access specific edge among list of edges a mesh contains)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do it using the link_edges of each vertice as input.

```
import bpy, bmesh

print("*"*20)

def intersection(V1, V2): 
    
    if V1 != V2:
        for e in V1.link_edges: 
            if e.other_vert(V1) is V2:
                return e.index
    else:
        return -1


obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

if hasattr(bm.verts, "ensure_lookup_table"): 
    bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

V1 = bm.verts[0]
V2 = bm.verts[7]

print(intersection(V1, V2))
```

Comment: Great idea using link edges to avoid looping over all edges. `for e in v1.link_edges: if e.other_vert(v1) is v2: return e.index` ... or return None if the two verts are not an edge.  Avoid using built in types eg `list`, as variables.